# Can you run Oracle's AVG() function on values in the same row?

Tags: sql, oracle, average

I have a dataset like this:

```
+---------+--------+--------+
| Student | Score1 | Score2 |
+---------+--------+--------+
|       1 |     23 |     40 |
|       2 |     12 |     10 |
|       3 |     54 |     90 |
+---------+--------+--------+
```

I want to calculate the mean of the 2 scores on each row. In theory this is pretty simple - just do `(score1 + score2/2)`. However, I run into problems if one of the values is NULL, having to make extensive use of `NVL`. The `AVG()` function would take care of all of this for me, but this is designed for averaging multiple rows. Is there any way of using AVG on values in the same row?

## Update

This is what I have at the moment which deals with all the possibilities (to my knowledge). However, I think there must be a cleaner way?

```
SELECT 
  T1.STUDENT, 
  T1.SCORE1, 
  T1.SCORE2, 
  (NVL(T1.SCORE1,0) + NVL(T1.SCORE2,0))/DECODE((NVL2(t1.SCORE1,1,0) + NVL2(t1.SCORE2,1,0)),0,NULL,(NVL2(t1.SCORE1,1,0) + NVL2(t1.SCORE2,1,0))) AS AVG_SCORE 
FROM STUDENTS T1;
```

Comment: @Farhęg, does it take care of divide by 1 or 2, depending on if one of the columns is NULL or not?

Comment: I don't understand, you mean `(nvl(Score1,0)+nvl(Score2,0))/2` don't work!!?? am I right?

Comment: If one of the values is null, you want to divide by 1, or?

Comment: @Farhęg if score1 was 1 and score2 was NULL, if you used your calculation it would return 0.5. In this case it should return 1 because there is only one actual value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your method is a good one.  I would write it as:

```
select student,
       ((coalesce(score1, 0) + coalesce(score2, 0)) /
        nullif(nvl2(score1, 1, 0) + nvl2(score2, 1, 0), 0)
       ) as score_avg
```

The advantage of this method (or the method in your question) is that it is easy to add more scores.

That said, having columns with basically the same name suggests that you should be using a junction table instead of multiple columns.

Answer (score 1):

what about this:

```
select student,
       case 
       when score1 is null and score2 is not null then score2
       when score1 is not null and score2 is null then score1
       when score1 is null and score2 is null then 0
       else (score1 + score2)/2 end
from your_table
```

Comment: One minor detail, you missed case's trailing end. And perhaps when both are null, 0 should be returned?

Comment: @jarlh surely if both were null then the result should be null?

Comment: @jarlh, thanks for your comment the missed word added.

Answer (score 1):

An alternative way would be to use `UNION ALL` to unify your score columns into one and then use a plain `AVG` / `GROUP BY`:

```
SELECT student, avg(score) AS score
  FROM (SELECT T1.STUDENT, 
               T1.SCORE1 AS score
          FROM STUDENTS T1
        UNION ALL
        SELECT T1.STUDENT, 
               T1.SCORE2 AS score
          FROM STUDENTS T1)
 GROUP BY student
 ORDER BY student
```

Answer (score 1):

what about this?

```
select student, avg(scorevalue) from
(select s1.student, 1 as scorefield, s1.score1 as scorevalue from students s1
union
select s2.student, 2 as scorefield, s2.score2 as scorevalue from students s2)
group by student
```